# QHash of function pointers for variable setting after XML parsing: insane?

Tags: c++, qt

I am parsing and storing data I get from a server in XML format.  The application is a thin client that asks for server-side data like this very frequently.  A few of the variables will be uris that trigger more network calls. The data is in the form:

```
<object>
    <var1>value</var1>
    ...
    <varN>value</varN>
</object>
```

There are ~50 variables in object. The object is mirrored by a MyObject class which has getters and setters for all the variables (which are of different types, and will be accessed by various other classes).

I've been using QXmlStreamReader which is fine, but I end up with a lot of

```
if (reader.name() == "var1")
{
    ...
}
```

entries, and I'm thinking there must be a better way?

I wrote some quick prototype code where MyObject has a function that takes `(name, entry)`, and indexes by `name` into a QHash of function pointers, that returns the setter to entry, which it calls passing `entry`.  This feels un-Qt-ish, and like something that will confuse a possible future maintainer:

In the header:

```
typedef void (Foo::*setValue)(QString& value);
QHash<QString, Foo::setValue> m_settersMap;
```

.cpp:

```
MyObject::MyObject(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    m_settersMap["var1"] = &MyObject::setVar1;
    m_settersMap["var2"] = &MyObject::setVar2;
    ...
    m_settersMap["varN"] = &MyObject::setVarN;
}

void MyObject::set(QString &name, QString &entry)
{
    MyObject *foo = this;
    MyObject::setValue setter;
    setter = m_settersMap.value(key);
    (*foo.*setter)(value);
}

void MyObject::setVar1(QString &entry)
{
    m_foo1 = entry;
}

...
```

and from the XML handler:

```
MyObject foo;

...

if(reader.isStartElement())
{
    foo.set(reader.name(), reader.readEntryText());
}
```

This way there's way less copy-pasta in the XML handler, but there's added overhead of the QHash and the possible confusion of a non-straightforward implementation (and my nagging suspicion this is not The Way To Do It).

So is this legit or insane, and have I missed something blindingly obvious?

Comment: You don't really mean `QHash`, do you? You mean `QMap`, right? This looks like a typical use for it to me. (But your code isn't close to compiling.)

Comment: Is there a big difference between QHash and QMap when dealing with ~50 short strings? I just defaulted to QHash, I don't have a justification beyond expecting it to be faster, and not needing serial access of variables.

Comment: But dabhaid...your source code (which still doesn't compile) has `QMap`!

Comment: Ah, I see now, I changed that immediately after copying the snippet - I'm sorry for the confusion TonyK! I'll edit it for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you another, "easier" solution which will help you to:

1) Have much less code and make *your* code readable
2) Do not overwhelm another objects with function calls

So you can use [QObject properties](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qobject.html#property) to do that. And your code would look like as simple as:

```
// parsing the XML here via QXmlStreamReader
...
QObject *object = new QObject;
...
object->setProperty(reader.name(), reader.value());
```

And then you can refer to a variable of you object in the code like this:

```
QString name = object->property("var1").toString();
```

You may want to extend QObject to get rid of necessity of calling .toString() or something like that all the time.

Comment: Ah, thanks Barbaris, I figured there was a much more Qt-like solution, this is indeed easier and more readable.